# Joining a List<String> in Java with commas and "and"

Tags: java, apache-commons

Given a list

```
List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();
l.add("one");
l.add("two");
l.add("three");
```

I have a method

```
String join(List<String> messages) {
        if (messages.isEmpty()) return "";
        if (messages.size() == 1) return messages.get(0);
        String message = "";
        message = StringUtils.join(messages.subList(0, messages.size() -2), ", ");
        message = message + (messages.size() > 2 ? ", " : "") + StringUtils.join(messages.subList(messages.size() -2, messages.size()), ", and ");
        return message;
    }
```

which, for l, produces "one, two, and three".
My question is, is there a standard (apache-commons) method that does the same?, eg

```
WhatEverUtils.join(l, ", ", ", and ");
```

To clarify. My problem is not getting this method to work. It works just as I want it to, it's tested and all is well. My problem is that I could not find some apache-commons-like module which implements such functionality. Which surprises me, since I cannot be the first one to need this.

But then maybe everyone else has just done

```
StringUtils.join(l, ", ").replaceAll(lastCommaRegex, ", and");
```

Comment: I don't think there's such an open source library, but I advise using a resource bundles since not all languages use the English word "and".

Comment: @slipset, why don't you use some join from known library and just modify it a bit? Notice that "and" is English word, so if such library would exist, it had to have multi languages support

Comment: I might have been unclear, but I have written the method I show in my question, and it works just as I want.

Comment: There is a good answer for this here: [Join strings with different last delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34936891/411282)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a more comprehensive solution, there is a brilliant [NLG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_generation) library for that - [SimpleNLG](https://github.com/simplenlg/simplenlg)

```
//initialize 
NLGFactory nlgFactory = new NLGFactory(Lexicon.getDefaultLexicon());
Realiser realiser = new Realiser(lexicon);
CoordinatedPhraseElement cp = nlgFactory.createCoordinatedPhrase();
cp.setConjunction("and");


//code begins here
List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();
l.add("one");
l.add("two");
l.add("three");
l.forEach(cp::addCoordinate);


//output
String output = realiser.realise(cp).toString();
```

This can support any number of array elements without needing to do ugly hacks like "remove last comma".

Answer (score 69):

In Java 8 you can use `String.join()` like following:

```
Collection<String> elements = ....;
String result = String.join(", ", elements);
```

Comment: This does not give the "and" requested in the question

Answer (score 15):

What about [join](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#join%28java.util.Collection,%20char%29) from:
[org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html)

Example:

```
StringUtils.join(new String[] { "one", "two", "three" }, ", "); // one, two, three
```

To have "and" or ", and" you can simple replace the last comma.

Comment: That's not producing `"one, two, and three"` as the OP requested. Observe: He's using that `join` method in his question

Comment: @Lukas, but you can replace the last comma, right? I don't see sense to have library which add for me this "and" in join method.

Answer (score 15):

With Java 8, you can use streams with joiners.

```
Collection<String> strings;
...
String commaDelimited = strings.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(","));
// use strings.parallelStream() instead, if you think
//   there are gains to be had by doing fork/join
```

Answer (score 13):

I like using Guava for this purpose. Neat and very useful:

```
Joiner.on(",").join(myList)
```

This kind of code has been written time and time again and you should rather be freed implementing your specific implementation logic.

If you use maven, herewith the dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>28.1-jre</version>
</dependency>
```

It has a bunch of other wonderful cool features too!

This will produce the string "one, two, and three".

```
List<String> originalList = Arrays.asList("one", "two", "three");
Joiner.on(", ")
    .join(originalList.subList(0, originalList.size() - 1))
    .concat(", and ")
    .concat(originalList.get(originalList.size() - 1));
```

Comment: -1 This would produce `", and one"` if there is only one element, `"one"`.

Answer (score 9):

To produce grammatical output in English there are 3 cases to consider when concatenating a list of strings:

1. "A"
2. "A and B"
3. "A, B, and C.

This can be accomplished using standard Java or Guava like below. The solutions are basically the same and just up to preference what you want to use.

```
import com.google.common.base.Joiner;
import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList;

import org.junit.Test;

import java.util.List;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

public class JoinListTest {

    @Test
    public void test_join() {
        // create cases (don't need to use ImmutableList builder from guava)
        final List<String> case1 = new ImmutableList.Builder<String>().add("A").build();
        final List<String> case2 = new ImmutableList.Builder<String>().add("A", "B").build();
        final List<String> case3 = new ImmutableList.Builder<String>().add("A", "B", "C").build();
        // test with standard java
        assertEquals("A", joinListGrammaticallyWithJava(case1));
        assertEquals("A and B", joinListGrammaticallyWithJava(case2));
        assertEquals("A, B, and C", joinListGrammaticallyWithJava(case3));
        // test with guava
        assertEquals("A", joinListGrammaticallyWithGuava(case1));
        assertEquals("A and B", joinListGrammaticallyWithGuava(case2));
        assertEquals("A, B, and C", joinListGrammaticallyWithGuava(case3));
    }

    private String joinListGrammaticallyWithJava(final List<String> list) {
        return list.size() > 1
                ? String.join(", ", list.subList(0, list.size() - 1))
                    .concat(String.format("%s and ", list.size() > 2 ? "," : ""))
                    .concat(list.get(list.size() - 1))
                : list.get(0);
    }

    private String joinListGrammaticallyWithGuava(final List<String> list) {
        return list.size() > 1
                ? Joiner.on(", ").join(list.subList(0, list.size() - 1))
                    .concat(String.format("%s and ", list.size() > 2 ? "," : ""))
                    .concat(list.get(list.size() - 1))
                : list.get(0);
    }

}
```

Comment: @FerranNegre you are correct.  The methods assume that a list of non-empty strings will be passed in.  It would be simple enough to filter the list before passing it in or else added into these methods.  Didn't warrant a downvote but sure.  Ok.

Comment: +1 - this is the answer that address the 'and' bit. The joiners are great but not the right tool for the question.

Comment: To use on lower Android API levels, you can use `TextUtils.join` instead of `String.join`

Answer (score 6):

Other answers talk about "replacing the last comma", which isn't safe in case the last term itself contains a comma.

Rather than use a library, you can just use one (albeit long) line of JDK code:

```
public static String join(List<String> msgs) {
    return msgs == null || msgs.size() == 0 ? "" : msgs.size() == 1 ? msgs.get(0) : msgs.subList(0, msgs.size() - 1).toString().replaceAll("^.|.$", "") + " and " + msgs.get(msgs.size() - 1);
}
```

See a [live demo](http://ideone.com/mBZInA) of this code handling all edge cases.

---

FYI, here's a more readable two-liner:

```
public static String join(List<String> msgs) {
    int size = msgs == null ? 0 : msgs.size();
    return size == 0 ? "" : size == 1 ? msgs.get(0) : msgs.subList(0, --size).toString().replaceAll("^.|.$", "") + " and " + msgs.get(size);
}
```

Comment: Swap ", and " for " and " above if you like the Oxford comma!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know any Apache String joiner that can support adding `and` in the joined String.

Here's an untested code that will do what you asked:

```
public static String join(String separator, List<String> mList, boolean includeAndInText) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int count = 0;

    for (String m: mList) {
        if (includeAndInText && (count + 1 != mList.size())) {
            sb.append (" and ");
        }

        sb.append(m);
        count++;
        if (count < mList.size()) {
            sp.append(separator);
        }       
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: sorry, but I don't think this is the best approach to this problem. IMO we should use something which exists (e.g. join from Apache) and modify it a bit to get " and ", " or " or something what we expect to have.

Comment: @smas, ok, I disagree. Changing an existing library to conform to your **only** requirement is not an obvious choice since (and I don't believe) you will commit your change to Apache. Plus, if another version of `StringUtils` gets released, you will have to maintain it and make sure that your change isn't affected (deleted). I say, leave the library implementation AS-IS and write your own Utility class.

Comment: I diagree also. In business world well-known libraries like StringUtils are used very often to avoid reinventing the wheel. If you aware of some changes, you write unit tests. For this case writing join on your own only because "and" must be there is waste of time, money and Object Oriented Programming style.

Answer (score 1):

Improved version from Bohemian♦'s answer. You can choose to remove the nulled items check on personal preferences.

```
/** Auto Concat Wrapper
 *  Wraps a list of string with comma and concat the last element with "and" string.
 *  E.g: List["A", "B", "C", "D"] -> Output: "A, B, C and D"
 * @param elements
 */
public static String join(List<String> elements){
    if(elements==null){return "";}
    List<String> tmp = new ArrayList<>(elements);
    tmp.removeAll(Collections.singleton(null)); //Remove all nulled items

    int size = tmp.size();
    return size == 0 ? "" : size == 1 ? tmp.get(0) : String.join(", ", tmp.subList(0, --size)).concat(" and ").concat(tmp.get(size));
}
```

Test results:

```
List<String> w = Arrays.asList("A");
List<String> x = Arrays.asList("A", "B");
List<String> y = Arrays.asList("A", "B", null, "C");
List<String> z = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C", "D");
System.out.println(join(w));//A
System.out.println(join(x));//A and B
System.out.println(join(y));//A, B and C
System.out.println(join(z));//A, B, C and D
```

Answer (score 0):

In this way we can join

```
List<Long> ids = new ArrayList<>();
String idsAsString = String.join(",", ids);
System.out.println(idsAsString);
```