# Join strings with different last delimiter

Tags: java, string, java-8, java-stream

Using `stream.collect(Collectors.joining(", "))` I can easily join all the strings of my stream delimited by a comma. A possible result would be `"a, b, c"`. But what if I want the last delimiter to be different. For example to be `" and "` such that I get `"a, b and c"` as result. Is there an easy solution?

Comment: To be honest -- no, there isn't.  `Collectors.joining` uses some pretty awkward tricks that break down completely when you try doing something like this.

Comment: Implement your own [`Collector`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html). As for "easy", that's a matter of skill and opinion.

Comment: @Andreas Is it possible to implement such a collector? How would the collector know when to use the special delimiter?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31044041/how-do-i-iterate-over-a-stream-in-java-using-for this question has a way of converting it into and array (one liner.) Then you can just iterate over it and add your custom delimiters. Should be pretty simple to do with an array :)

Comment: @erickson If you want the Oxford comma, specify the delimiters as `", "` and `", and "`. (I also prefer it.)

Comment: Actually, that won't quite work, but I've added an Oxford comma variant to my answer.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If they are already in a list, no stream is needed; simply join a sublist of all but the last element and concat the other delimiter and the final element:

```
int last = list.size() - 1;
String joined = String.join(" and ",
                    String.join(", ", list.subList(0, last)),
                    list.get(last));
```

Here's a version that does the above using `Collectors.collectingAndThen:`

```
stream.collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toList(),
    joiningLastDelimiter(", ", " and ")));

public static Function<List<String>, String> joiningLastDelimiter(
        String delimiter, String lastDelimiter) {
    return list -> {
                int last = list.size() - 1;
                if (last < 1) return String.join(delimiter, list);
                return String.join(lastDelimiter,
                    String.join(delimiter, list.subList(0, last)),
                    list.get(last));
            };
}
```

This version can also handle the case where the stream is empty or only has one value. Thanks to Holger and Andreas for their suggestions which greatly improved this solution.

I had suggested in a comment that the Oxford comma could be accomplished with this using `", "` and `", and"` as the delimiters, but that yields incorrect results of `"a, and b"` for two elements, so just for fun here's one that does Oxford commas correctly:

```
stream.collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toList(),
    joiningOxfordComma()));

public static Function<List<String>, String> joiningOxfordComma() {
    return list -> {
                int last = list.size() - 1;
                if (last < 1) return String.join("", list);
                if (last == 1) return String.join(" and ", list);
                return String.join(", and ",
                    String.join(", ", list.subList(0, last)),
                    list.get(last));
            };
}
```

Comment: Also, I pasted that into Eclipse, and get a compile error, that can be fixed by explicitly giving the types: `Collector.<String, List<String>, String>of(`

Comment: Hmm, `javac` doesn't give me a compile error, but I can add the explicit types. What version of Eclipse?

Comment: Since here the only relevant function is the *finisher*, you could simply use `Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toList(), list -> { … })`. By the way, you could also use `String.join(lastDelimiter, String.join(delimiter, list.subList(0, last)), list.get(last))` for the return statement.

Comment: The proposed solutions fail for the empty list.

Comment: ...and fails also for the 1-element list

Comment: @Ivin I just tried both the `joiningLastDelimiter()` and `joiningOxfordComma()` solutions, and they both work fine for the empty list and the 1-element list. Only the first solution would have to be modified with guards for those cases.

Comment: This can be a bit simpler without returning a Function, i.e., just a static method taking a List and returning a String (and then refer to it for the `finisher` argument with a function reference, `MyClass::joining...`)

Answer (score 7):

If you're fine with `"a, b, and c"`, then it's possible to use [`mapLast`](http://amaembo.github.io/streamex/javadoc/one/util/streamex/StreamEx.html#mapLast-java.util.function.Function-) method of my [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex) library which extends standard Stream API with additional operations:

```
String result = StreamEx.of("a", "b", "c")
                        .mapLast("and "::concat)
                        .joining(", "); // "a, b, and c"
```

The `mapLast` method applies given mapping to the last stream element keeping others unchanged. I even have similar [unit-test](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex/blob/9672cb18b708ee009c88c82c80af96d5f3937e95/src/test/java/one/util/streamex/StreamExTest.java#L1489).

Comment: This is not the answer the OP wants, but if you're a fan of the Oxford comma, this answer is grammatically "more" correct. Thanks Tagir.

Answer (score 1):

Try joining the last 2 strings first with `stream.collect(Collectors.joining(" and "))`

Then join all remaining strings and this new string with the code you used in your question: `stream.collect(Collectors.joining(", "))`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for *old Java solution*, using [Guava libraries](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) would be easy.

```
    List<String> values = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c");
    String output = Joiner.on(",").join(values);
    output = output.substring(0, output.lastIndexOf(","))+" and "+values.get(values.size()-1);
    System.out.println(output);//a,b and c
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String str = "a , b , c , d";
String what_you_want = str.substring(0, str.lastIndexOf(","))
        + str.substring(str.lastIndexOf(",")).replace(",", "and");

// what_you_want is : a , b , c and d
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    List<String> names = Arrays.asList("Thomas", "Pierre", "Yussef", "Rick");
    int length = names.size();
    String result = IntStream.range(0, length - 1).mapToObj(i -> {
        if (i == length - 2) {
            return names.get(i) + " and " + names.get(length - 1);
        } else {
            return names.get(i);
        }
    }).collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a Streams-API solution but is pretty fast. Enjoy!

```
public static final <E> String join(
    Iterable<E> objects, String separator, String lastSeparator) 
{
    Objects.requireNonNull(objects);

    final String sep = separator == null ? "" : separator;
    final String lastSep = lastSeparator == null ? sep : lastSeparator;

    final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    final Iterator<E> iterator = objects.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        final E next = iterator.next();
        if (builder.length() > 0) {
            if (iterator.hasNext()) {
                builder.append(sep);
            }
            else {
                builder.append(lastSep);
            }
        }
        builder.append(next);
    }

    return builder.toString();
}
```